# AR Glasses compatible with Aframe.io framework

Tags: aframe

While I know Aframe.io does not officially support AR glasses like Xreal, Viture, and others I would like to know if anyone has had success using usb-c glasses with Aframe.io framework including stereo 3d support? Does the system browser, Chrome, have access to the left and right views allowing aframe to controll what the user sees in left and right eyes. Really appreciate responses and insights.

I know you can control stereo vision on Oculus Quest headsets, looking to do same with AR glasses.